# Tor > vanity hostname and private_key > moved from other server > not working

Tags: private-key

I recently moved a tor hidden service from one rpi to another. Everything works dandy, until I exchange the hostname and private_key files to a vanity V2 onion I own. In torrc I changed the version to V2, and I tried

1. Replacing the entire files with my own hostname & private_key FILES
2. Keeping the tor-generated files, and only replacing their content to that of my vanity hostname & private_key content
3. Checking permissions (everything set to Debian-tor)
4. re-installing the entire OS, etc.

Nothing seems to be firing it up...

What am I missing?

Comment: Some suggestions: - Have you tried checking that the `torrc` references the same directory? - Ensure the new keys/hostname files have correct permissions (same as e.g. `/var/lib/tor/`) - Checked the log?

Comment: thanks! The setup works with the newly generated keys and hostname. Only when I replace key and hostname with my "old" vanity files does it crap up. 1. Yes, the torrc is correctly set up, and points to the correct directories 2. Yes, the permissions are correct. Even used the tor created files and only pasted the content of my "old" files in as not to disturb the permission settings 3. Unfortunately, and for some unknown reason, my tor doesn't create a log... and idea on how to activate that?